# Measurement Uncertainties and LOQ values

Tags: measurement-error

I have a report that lists four polyaromatic hydrocarbon components as <1 ug/kg each, with a lower bound of 0.0 and an upper bound of 4 for the sum.

The clients specification for the sum is 1.5 max.

To make sense of this I need to use the MU that should go around the sum.  The legislation says use the upper bound for compliance but take MU into account.

Normal sd estimates are rectangular, triangular and normal but I suspect the true distribution would skew towards zero.  Sort of a half triangular.

How do I proceed with estimating the MU is this situation?

Comment: What exactly does "MU" refer to?  Even if it means "measurement uncertainty," just what version of uncertainty would it be?  Note that without supporting QA/QC documentation, you cannot just assume some distribution of the results between zero and the LoQ.  Another consideration is to ask why the lab was using a method with an LoQ of 1 when the client needed a limit of 1.5: surely the QAPjP specified a lower LoQ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  Yes, it does mean Measurement Uncertainty.  Usually considered to be sd x an expansion coefficient, usually 2.  The back story is an external lab did the testing for us, for a sample provided by our client.  The 1.5 specification comes from the client's client, so the two don't know each other and there is no guarantee the 1.5 is anything other than aspirational.  So, rephrasing my question: if you have results for four residues, PAHs, thare are reported individually as <1 ug/kg, is there a way to estimate the uncertainty of the sum other than 2±2 ug/kg?

Comment: I would suggest that $2\pm 2$ is incorrect: based on the information available to you, the sum is some unknown value between $0$ and $4.$  The LoQ already incorporates information about the SD (although typically, at least in environmental work in the US, it incorporates it incorrectly, but that's another matter altogether). The distinction between "$2\pm 2$" and "$\lt 4$" is that the former suggests there is some kind of probability distribution and $2$ is a "typical" or "expected" value, whereas the latter presumes no probability distribution at all and suggests no typical value.

Comment: (Continued) The two expressions would be treated very differently in statistical analyses: $2\pm 2$ would be viewed as $2$ and the $\pm 2$ would be used as a measure of uncertainty, whereas $\lt 4$ would be viewed as a *left censored* value.

Comment: Granted, the 2±2 was a bit flippant perhaps.  The reality is the 'true' result will most probably be closer to 0 than 4 but it doesn't help in figuring out how to give an indication of compliance in this case.  I appreciate your time and patience but it seems that the problem is not about to be solved.  Cheers, Lee.

Comment: Based on the information you have disclosed, $\lt 4$ is the most precise solution that can be defended. If your belief that the true concentration will be closer to zero is based on any explicit assumptions or information, then please supply those.